# Can I poll for file to run another code?

Tags: network-programming, clang

**Client side:**

```
#define BUFFSIZE      4096
main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
  int fd,i,n;
  char buff[BUFFSIZE];
  extern char *pname;

  pname = argv[0];
  argv++; argc--;
  fd=0;
  i=0;
  do{
     if(arg>0 && (fd=my_open(argv[i],0)) <0) {
         err_ret("cant open %s", argv[i]);
         continue;
     }
     while((n=read(fd,buff,BUFFSIZE))>0)
         if (write(1,buff,n) !=n)
              err_sys("write error:);
         if(n<0) 
              err_sys("read error");
     }  while(++i<argc);
        exit(0);
 }
```

**Server side:**

```
main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *intv[];
{
          int fd;
          extern int errno;
          extern char *pname;

          pname= argv[0];
          if(argc !=4)
                err_quit("open file <sockfd#> <filename><mode>");
          if((fd=open(argv[2],atoi(argv[3]))) < 0)
                 exit((errno>0) ? errno:255);
           exit(sendfile(atoi(argv[1]),fd));
}
```

If I send a config file from client to server like this, then can I run a polling code on server which runs a python code on receiving config file.

Comment: Rejected means will my question be put on hold?

Comment: It is c lang! I will remove python tag